# Laravel Model Relationship on associative table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

So, I've got a `File` model, and I've got a `Dependency` model that will indicate whether a particular `File` instance is dependent on another. (Think package management.) The `dependencies` table is very straightforward:

```
id                 PRIMARY
file_id            INTEGER UNSIGNED
depends_on_file_id INTEGER UNSIGNED
```

The `files` table also uses `id` for a primary key.

But I have not been able to wrap my head around the right way to build the relationship on the model. I thought it would be:

```
public function deps()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('App\File', 'dependencies', 'file_id', 'id');
    }
```

But when I try to use it:

```
>>> $f = App\File::find(2);
=> App\File {#706
     id: 2,
     {redacted irrelevant properties here},
   }
>>> $f->deps();
=> null
```

Not getting a collection at all. There is a single row of seeded data, where `file_id 2 depends_on_file_id 1`.

What am I missing here please?

Answer (score 1):

Saying by the way you designed the tables, it's not many-to-many, but **one-to-many** relationship you've got here: one file can have many dependencies. The fact you have 2 foreign keys on the `dependencies` table doesn't make in many-to-many, as both foreign keys reference the same table - `files`.

Once you've set up the [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) correctly, you're good to go.

**File.php model**

```
public function departments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Department', 'file_id', 'id');
}
```

**Department.php model**

```
public function files() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\File');
}
```

The relation above was not tested, but you get the idea.

Comment: That is still returning an empty set, but for the time being I'm working around it by doing e.g., `$d = App\Dependency::where('file_id', 2)->get();`. I appreciate the sanity check though, I've been starting at models for long enough that relationships aren't making any sense.

Comment: Seems like the relationship is incorrectly set-up. As I wrote, I did not test it. But I'd say you're on the right path.